# OOP: Passing new Object as a parameter or creating it inside constructor?

Tags: design, object-oriented, architecture, object-oriented-design, class-design

I have three subclasses that inherit from `Hero`:

- `Warrior`
- `Magician`
- `Amazon`

The three of them hold a `Weapon`, that is always the same one:

- `Warrior` always holds a `Sword` (that inherits from `Weapon`)
- `Magician` always holds a `Wand` (that inherits from `Weapon`)
- `Amazon` always holds a `Bow` (that inherits from `Weapon`)

I have in mind several solutions, like:

1. Passing the weapon as a parameter of the constructor (should this be done from a Factory? In this case, when creating a `Warrior` it should come already with a `Sword`, and so on...)
2. Creating the specific weapon inside the constructor for each of the `Heroes`.

Thinking about further testing, **solution 1** will allow me to pass a mocked `Weapon` when creating the object. In the other hand, **solution 2** won't, and I guess I will not be fulfilling the principles of Unit Testing by isolating the unit (my `Hero`) from other components (the `Weapon`).

What do you think here?

Comment: I think that this is the worst of OO, and whatever training material you're using should be discarded for something a little more modern.

Comment: What about: https://ericlippert.com/2015/04/27/wizards-and-warriors-part-one/ and the other parts of it?

Comment: @Telastyn Hi. Could you please point me to some resources or keywords so that I can better understand what is wrong here and what are these modern solutions? A few more words about what ''this is the worst of OO"?

Comment: @delgan - I don't know of any articles off the top of my head, but the entire concept of implicitly encoding information (what class your hero is) in its type is not great. It would be much better if that information was explicitly encoded in data. The implicit coupling to type is fragile and leads to bugs (due to misunderstanding the implicit contract or forgetting to enforce it somewhere).

Comment: @Telastyn Thanks for taking the time to answer me. This is a very interesting concept, I had never thought about this point of view. I will try to find some readings on this subject. Just a note to myself unrelated to this comment: several answers here are referring to "composition vs aggregation" design, but it seems more accurate to speak about the [dependency injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_injection) technique.

Answer (score 5):

You are right when you say that solution 2 will not allow you to mock weapons, which hinders testing.
h
Another drawback of solution 2 is that it would create a coupling between two concrete classes, [which is not good](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_inversion_principle).

Instanting a weapon inside the constructor makes the relationship between Hero and Weapon one of [composition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_composition), which doesn't model the domain all that well, since weapons are not part of heroes, weapons can exist independently of heroes and viceversa. We all have seen movies where a mytical weapon lies dormant or remains hidden until a perticular hero it is destined for "activates" it or finds it, or an impostor manages to steal it ([sword on the rock](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Excalibur#Excalibur_and_the_Sword_in_the_Stone), etc.), so weapons can exist separatelly from heroes. Also, more often than not, heroes have their weapons made for them, for example greek god [Hephaestus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hephaestus#Hephaestus_and_Athena) was the blacksmith for the gods and made weapons for them, so the creation of weapons whould not happen in the constructor of the hero. In addition, when a hero is killed, the weapon remains. So, the relationship should be [aggregation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_composition#Aggregation).

So, IMHO option 2 is a no go and solution 1 is the way to go.

Answer (score 5):

Solution 3: allow each hero to be constructed **without** a weapon at all. Instead, give your Hero a public property for the Weapon he/she holds, and assign this property from outside whenever it is needed, or reassign it later. This property might be `null`, indicating currently the hero does not hold a weapon.

When creating entity classes like a "hero" class, I would avoid to implement anything of the specific game mechanics inside the objects. When, where and how weapons are created and passed around *is* part of that mechanics, so I recommend not to hardcode this into any of the objects.

Comment: I find what you are saying about keeping game mechanics away of the object interesting, and that is actually pretty much what I am looking for. I was just wondering, imagine the wizard can freeze other heroes, the amazon slow them down and the warrior stun them... some actions that will affect other heroes movement. Let's say each hero have a .move(x) method: the x will be reduced by the slow down or ignored by the stun. Should the hero itself know if they are having moving or would you keep this away? I think for me that would be part of a hero, .move() will end up moving whatever has to.

Comment: @charliebrownie: when I design real programs, I do not make these kind of decisions up front. I start typically with dumb entities with no methods at all. When implementing a use case where a nontrivial operation like "movement" is involved, I implement that operation somewhere "outside" the entity. Then I look which parts of that operation can be refactored into methods which fit into the abstraction of the particular class.

Comment: +1 In my answer I forgot to propose preciselly that. Not passing it in the constructor but in a setter. I focussed only on the composition vs aggregation.

Comment: This is a good solution approach. We can also extend the logic where multiple weapons can be attached to a particular Hero.

Answer (score 2):

The distinction you are talking about is between [aggregation and composition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/734891/aggregation-versus-composition).

Use composition when the lifetime of parts is the same as the lifetime of the containing class.  A Hand is a composite part of a Human, it would be normal to construct the composite parts within the class or the constructor of the whole.  Use the approach that most accurately reflects the usage.

Conversely Flour and Eggs are used to make a Cake they exist beforehand, so pass them into the Constructor of the Cake.  Hands grow with the person, so construct them within the class.  A simple rule of thumb is if X is **part** of Y then apply composition.

Use aggregation when the lifetime of parts is not constrained by the lifetime of the container.   A Weapon has a different lifetime to a person, it can be changed, it is picked up and it can be dropped.  It is constructed by a weapon smith and given,sold, found by the Hero.  A simple rule of thumb for aggregation is, if X is **used** (or any specific verb) by Y then apply aggregation.

```
Class Character {
  Hand right = new Hand();
  Hand left;

  Character() {
    left = new Hand();
    }

  public equipLeft(Weapon weapon) {
    left.equipped(weapon)
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Another good question when thinking about this: is this 1:1 or 1:many?  In other words, can a Hero carry 0 or many weapons?  Probably yes, right?  Even my D&D archer ranger who never melees also carries a rusty dull sword.  So passing exactly one weapon in a constructor, or automatically creating one, are both wrong.  As @Doc Brown suggested, you should have an `addWeapon()` method.  And probably a `removeWeapon()` too.

Answer (score -1):

The hero should create his/her own weapon internally because you stated each will always have the same hero-specific type. The weapon is like an arm (or a leg), it is just an inseparable part of the hero. So do not get distracted by testing dogma's and let your model be screwed up by them. It is unthinkable for a warrior to end up with a wand in his hands so you should not facilitate that. You could even say the whole weapon tree is non-sense because the flexibility of tossing different weapons around among heros is not needed or desired. Just integrate the hero-specific weapon into the hero.

Comment: Terms like 'always' and 'never' are misleading when weighing up options for your design (unless you have a fully functional and reliable crystal ball, but I'm assuming you don't have one of those!).     The principal benefit of dependency injection is [loosely-coupled code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loose_coupling) which avoids *[technical debt](https://martinfowler.com/bliki/TechnicalDebt.html)* and is easier to change later on.   Having loosely coupled code makes it easier to unit test, but that is a secondary benefit.

Comment: @Ben  We are all aware of those benefits, the point is they do not serve any purpose here. The OP specifically states "The three of them hold a Weapon, that is always the same one". Warrior will not be waving a wand and he will never wear a tutu. So in this case encapsulation and keeping the scope of things tight outweighs the anticipated need for flexibility. YAGNI, good things can be noise when misplaced.